# laravel hasone get name from id

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have a table with:

```
id
employee_name
manager_id
```

In this table, manager id is a foreign key to id in same table.

I have another table with projects

```
id
employee_id
```

In this table, employee_id is a foreign key to id in the employee table

I try to get the name from the manager_id like this in the controller:

```
public function show(Employee $managers, $id)
{

    $manager = $managers::find($id)->manager;
    \Debugbar::info($manager);

}
```

And my App\Employee file is like this:

```
class Employee extends Model {

    protected $table = 'employees';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Projects');
    }
    public function manager()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Employee');
    }

}
```

The proble is I get:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'employees.employee_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `employees` where `employees`.`employee_id` = 1 and `employees`.`employee_id` is not null limit 1)
```

To me it shows that it is taking employee_id in the sal statement from the other function where it should only take id as it is in the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change:

```
public function manager()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Employee');
}
```

into

```
public function manager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee','manager_id');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without the **manager_id** I expect the 2nd parameter is for when you have an id that does not follow the **tablename_id** convention.

```
public function manager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
}
```